# Strange Error, I think it's related to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am getting the following compiler error on the package:

> package com.core.cronjob.mapping;

The Error :

> Internal compiler error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: info
>   cannot be null at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen.StackMapFrame.addStackItem(StackMapFrame.java:81)

I don't think it's the code.
I'm using **Ant 1.9.4** to build the project  and **Eclipse Mars.1 Release .
(4.5.1)**

The compiler version is : **javac 1.7.0_79**

Was anyone encountered this error before?

Thanks

Comment: might it be [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=241044)?

Comment: As Kevin says, there is a log on this bug on the eclipse bugzilla [this one for 4.5](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471589) (or [that one](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=465900))

Comment: Yes, it's the same bug.

Comment: There are several bug reports in Eclipse Bugzilla for this, such as [471589](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471589)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment, it's indeed an Eclipse bug, recurrent since Eclipse 3.X.

The last time I encountered this one it was fix with an Eclipse upgrade but since you're already up to date; you may try to downgrade to Luna (4.4) ? or wait for Eclipse to fix this one in a new RC..

As far as I know there is no workaround (Uninstall/Reinstall might also do some good..)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a older post, however, I did experience this using IntelliJ SpringBoot project on a Junit/Mockito test class.

With the help from smarter and more experienced Java guru's, they helped me resolve the issue.

We had to comment out all the code in the class and un-comment out sections until we found the statement causing the error.

It was this setId(configId++), we tried ++configId with no success.  We then realized the class member variable is a 'Long' and the local variable is a 'long'.

Change the local to 'Long' and it compiled.

```
1. ERROR in C:\JenkinsJAAS\workspace\ohsu\woa-ohsu-parent\master\di-config-ohsu\di-config-service-impl-ohsu\src\test\java\com.ge.ps.diconfig.data.impl\ConfigDataServiceImplTest.java (at line 0)

    /*

    ^

Internal compiler error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: info cannot be null at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen.StackMapFrame.addStackItem(StackMapFrame.java:81)

----------

info cannot be null
```